# How to get properties of beacon kontakt?

Tags: ios, macos, ios7, ibeacon, estimote

I need to connect to the beacon using the sdk provided by the kontakt beacon ?Does i want to know the API key for this to fetch the properties of beacon such as power,uuid,proximity etc??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you need to know the apikey which you will get from there account after registation

Comment: Hi Johny, I want to get API key but I have a problem which is to get Order Identification Number (OIN) on kontakt.io panel registration. They want to this number to register. If I register, I will get API key from panel but I couldn't register. Can you help me ? Thank you.

Comment: your OIN will be written on the document which you recieved with beacons when you purchased.here is the link which gives instruction to get OIN:-https://support.kontakt.io/hc/en-gb/articles/201499312

Comment: Hi again @johnykumar I have problem with connection to kontakt iBeacon. I have a question on this link. Here is the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694029/get-properties-of-kontakt-ibeacon  Could you help me ?