# Get properties of Kontakt iBeacon

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

I'm developing an `iBeacon` app and I want to get all properties of `Kontakt iBeacons`.

There are 2 or 3 topic about that in stackoverflow but nobody couldn't answer this.

My app is a global `iBeacon` project. I can see all properties of `Estimote iBeacons` also can change `major`,`minor` values. I did this with using connect method in `Estimote SDK` however I couldn't connect `Kontakt iBeacons`. I just accessed `major`,`minor` and `rssi` values with `Kontakt SDK`.

I have an `API key` to connect these `iBeacons` but I couldn't connect. I just want to learn way of accessing these values. Can anybody tell the way of this ?

Thank you, Halil.

Comment: try this which i post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
client=[KTKClient new];
client.apiKey=@"apikey";
locationManager=[KTKLocationManager new];
locationManager.delegate=self;
NSError *error;
NSArray *array=[client getRegionsError:&error];

[locationManager setRegions:array];
//[locationManager stopMonitoringBeacons];
[locationManager startMonitoringBeacons];
beaconManager = [KTKBeaconManager new];
beaconManager.delegate = self;
[beaconManager startFindingDevices];

- (void)locationManager:(KTKLocationManager *)locationManager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons{

    for (CLBeacon *beacon in beacons) {
    KTKBeacon *beaconData = [self _getDataForBeacon:beacon];
    if (beaconData) beaconsData[beacon] = beaconData;
    }
}

-(KTKBeacon *)_getDataForBeacon:(CLBeacon *)beacon
{
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.kontakt.io/beacon?proximity=%@&major=%@&minor=%@",
       [beacon.proximityUUID UUIDString],beacon.major,beacon.minor];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
[request setValue:@"apikey" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Api-Key"];
[request setValue:@"application/vnd.com.kontakt+json; version=2" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];
NSError * error1=nil;
NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error1];

 KTKBeacon *ktkBeacon = [[KTKBeacon alloc] initWithDictionary:dic];

NSLog(@"%@",dic);
return ktkBeacon;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for replying my question Johny. I will try this.

Comment: I found problem. For Estimote "didRangeBeacons" methods return type of beacon "ESTBeacon" but for Kontakt "didRangeBeacons" methods return type of beacon "CLBeacon" not return "KTKBeacon" type. Why this happen Johny ? What do you think about that ? Thank you Halil.

Comment: you have to create ktkbeacon with clbeacon

Comment: Johny I will accept your answer bro thank you, but how can I use "- (BOOL)connectWithPassword:(NSString *)password andError:(NSError **)error" method. Do you know ? Because If you want to access all properties of kontakt beacon you have to connect with password. My beacons have passwords but I couldn't use this method. Have you use this method?

Comment: I accessed ktkBeacon thank you bro. I just do connect with password to access all properties. Thank you thank you again !

Comment: i have not tried that but will try and reply u after that

Comment: Thank you Johny, I am waiting you. I opened question about it, If you have an answer, you can write there. Here is the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29742779/kontakt-ibeacon-returning-nil  Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Johny Kumar provides very helpful but ugly and outdated response. Somehow his code is the only example I can find of using the KontaktSDK API, so to shed some more light on the KontaktSDK API...

This is the swift version of Johny Kumar's answer with the new API

```
import KontaktSDK

func beaconManager(manager: KTKBeaconManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: KTKBeaconRegion) {
    print("Ranged beacons count: \(beacons.count)")

    for beacon in beacons {
        print(beacon)

        let uuid = beacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString
        let major = beacon.major
        let minor = beacon.minor
        let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = ["proximity":uuid, "major" : major, "minor": minor]

        KTKCloudClient.sharedInstance().getObjects(KTKDevice.self, parameters: parameters){
            response, error in
            guard let objects = response?.objects else {return}

            for object in objects{
                if let device = object as? KTKDevice {
                    print("device: \(device)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you would like to get the associated actions for a beacon (or device)

```
func fetchActions(device: KTKDevice) {
    let params = ["uniqueId":device.uniqueID]

    KTKCloudClient.sharedInstance().getObjects(KTKAction.self, parameters: params) { response ,error in
        guard let objects = response?.objects else {return}
        for object in objects{
            if let action = object as? KTKAction {
                print(action.url)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's pretty terrible that Kontakt doesnt provide any example of how to do this, so if you're reading this from Kontakt please put this in your example document.