# Kontakt iBeacon returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

I have an app which is showing properties of iBeacons which brand of Estimote and `Kontakt`.

I have a problem with `Kontakt` iBeacons. The problem is ; some `properties` of Kontakt iBeacons are returning `nil` which properties are `firmware`,`password` and `managerUUID`. I had a same problem with Estimote but I solved with used connect method in Estimote delegate.

How can I `connect` Kontakt iBeacon? There isn't enough documentation on the Internet. I couldn't find anything. If I connect it, I think, It will show all properties. Anybody can help me ?

Thank you Halil.

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, there is enough documentation on the internet, on our site you have full documentation of SDK - http://docs.kontakt.io/ios-sdk/appledocs.
KTKClient is the class for getting beacons properties from Kontakt's cloud.

There are 2 main methods for getting beacons(main) properties:

**– deviceByUniqueID:withError:** - returns one KTKBeacon object if proper uniqueId was provided

**– devicesByType:withError:** - returns array of all manager's beacons(KTKBeacon objects if type was KTKDeviceTypeBeacon).
Thanks to them you will get info about **managerUUID**.

To get password you should use:

**– devicePassword:andMasterPassword:byUniqueId:withError:**

To get current firmware version you should connect to beacon and read it from its characteristic. Check class **KTKCharacteristcDescriptor.h** and characteristic **kKTKCharacteristicDescriptorTypeFirmwareRevision**.

I hope this answer clarified how to get those properties.